# Arduino Pro Mini IDE 1.8.4 avrdude: stk500recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: upload, arduino, windows-8.1

I was working on a project that I started a few months ago, and uploading seemed OK until randomly everything stopped. I've updated the IDE to the latest version (1.8.4), updated the Driver (USBTinyISP), disabled/enabled the COM port, tried multiple pro mini's, uploading example sketches, changed usb ports, and enabled verbose output during upload. What's weird is I can see the old serial monitor data printing from my previous upload changes this morning, so I know communication is working. The following is the message displayed after attempting to upload the sketch to the board.

```
Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, ATmega168 (3.3V, 8 MHz)"

Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\pxb07\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_814882\core\core_arduino_avr_pro_cpu_8MHzatmega168_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a
Sketch uses 3284 bytes (22%) of program storage space. Maximum is 14336 bytes.
Global variables use 335 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 689 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 1024 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega168 -carduino -PCOM8 -b19200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\pxb07\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_381498/SoftwareSerialExample.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM8
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x28

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't connected any jumper wires to the port 0 and 1 while uploading.

Comment: At times, while uploading a new sketch to the Arduino Mini, you need to press the reset button on the board immediately before pressing the upload button in the Arduino environment. Can you try this?

Comment: @Billa I've made sure nothing is connected to those pins on both boards.

Comment: @MilindDeore I've tried, but either my timing is off or it's just not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to [test loopback](http://www.instructables.com/id/Loopback-Test-For-Arduino-Uno/) to make sure the serial communication channel is intact. I am presuming that the board and port is selected properly.

If the loopback works, try reseting the board immediately just before you flash/upload the sketch to the board.

Comment: The loopback test works, I get my input echoed back to me.

Comment: I can think of following possibilities, your PC is not recognising the board, can you check in the 'Device Manager' and under 'Ports', do you see Arduino here and the same COM port is selected in the IDE too? If is all fine, upgrade driver to the latest and greatest.

Comment: It looks like the port comes up both in the IDE and in the Device manager. I found the latest firmware (I'm using the FTDI) and I'm still having the problem. I pressed reset right before I clicked upload and it's not uploading. I thought it may be the arduino but both appear to be running fine and the loopback works on both with no problem.

Comment: for some reason when I try to get the board info it comes up as "Unknown Board". That seems weird as it's a pro mini, that's never been a problem.

Comment: wait! I apologize! I marked your answer as the correct one because it lead me to my resolution! Thank you! When I did the loopback test both boards seemed fine, but when you suggested the updated I stumbled onto the Device Manager list, and it looks as if it wasn't updated to the latest. So after I updated it, my board selection was an ATmega 168 (3.3 V 8MHz)  instead of an ATmega 328 (3.3 V 8MHz). 

Not exactly the direction, but you lead me down the correct path! Thank you again!